# Failing to set correct Qt version with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed Qt5.6 via repository from launchpad. I already changed the default version of Qt to this new one. (I modified the default.conf in /usr/lib//x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/).

Output of `qmake -v` :

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.0 in /opt/qt56/lib
```

I have troubles with setting up a CMake project within Qt Creator. As I rely on the Point Cloud Library, which is not easy for me to wrap in .pro files, I would like to stick with Cmake.

It seems the Qt 5.6 version is not found by cmake, because I get an error for including `QEnableSharedFromThis`:

> /home/hackenberg/pub3/simpletree/SimpleTree4/model/segment.h:7:
>   error: QEnableSharedFromThis: No such file or directory

This is contained in Qt module `Core`, and supported from Version 5.4 on.

Apparently, cmake does not find the right Qt version, which is strange as qmake points to the right one.

Here is my CmakeList.txt (without overhead of cpp and h files):

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
 project(pcl_visualizer_viewports)
 add_definitions(-fPIC)
 find_package(PCL 1.7.2 REQUIRED)
 set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
 set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
 find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
 add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set (project_SOURCES...)
set (project_HEADERS...)

ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE (simpleTree ${project_SOURCES})
include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (pcl_visualizer_demo pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcl_visualizer_demo ${PCL_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Core)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Switching to a pro file would help with the Qt version issue, but I have tried and PCL brings me to other problems.

Comment: start from basic, generate makefile project from command line `mkdir /tmp/build && cd /tmp/build && cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' path/to/src` and run `make VERBOSE=1` it print your include path and other staff.

Comment: @user1034749 Thanks for the comment, as expected make VERBOSE=1 shows the to other qt version is linked (-I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore). This is the standard installation folder from the QT5 in stable Ubuntu repositories, the version 5.6 is installed in /opt/qt56

Comment: then you should add `qmake` from `/opt/qt56` before other `qmake` to `PATH`, in console run `export PATH=/opt/qt56/??/bin:$PATH` and them `rm -fr /tmp/build/* && cd /tmp/build && cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles'` if this helps, run `qtcreator` from this console, and do not forget remove `CMakeCache.txt` from directory where `qtcreator` build your project. After the first configuration `cmake` rembeber path to your qmake and will work correctly.

Comment: `??` replace with suitable value

Comment: you need to `source /opt/qt56/bin/qt56-env.sh`, or better yet, add the contents to your `.bashrc` file. I'm pretty sure that CMake relies on `QTDIR` to find Qt. Here's an example of a [travis script](https://github.com/nholthaus/gtest-runner/blob/master/.travis.yml) that I use to build a qt 5.6 project on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @user1034749 this kind of works, it seems from make output that now correct qt is used. unfortunately i seem to use here a different compiler when running your console commands ( warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     ImprovementType improvement = ImprovementType::NO;
)

Comment: @nicolasholthaus did one time run the shell script. does not help with qt creator compilation. Also still the c++11 version error occurs when I follow the approach user1034749 recommended (console compilation)...

Comment: @Jan so add `-std=c++11` to your compiler options. Also, you have to run it every time you open a new terminal.